# How to activate gift card

Tags: magento-enterprise, gift-card

I want to activate the gift card div on shopping cart page. How can I do that on admin configuration? Also I can't remember if I comment it out so I want to ask also what is the path to check the gift card template?

[image]

I'm using Magento Enterprise version 1.14

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Gift Options Configuration**

The Gift Options configuration determines if customers have the option to add a gift
message for the complete order, and for individual items. The gift options must be
configured first for the website, and can then be overridden at the product leve

**To enable gift options:**

1. On the Admin menu, select System > Configuration. Then in the panel on the left,
   under Sales, select Sales.
2. Click to expand the Gift Options section. Then, set the following options according to
   your preference:

   - Allow Gift Messages on Order Level : Specify whether a gift message can be added for
     the entire order.
   - Allow Gift Messages for Order Items : Specify whether a gift message can be added for
     an individual order item
3. When complete, click the Save Config button.

---

**Gift Options** : Gift Options determine if customers have the option to add a gift message and to gift
wrap the product during checkout. To configure gift options for the store, see:
To set up gift options for a product:

**Step 1:** On the Admin menu, select `Catalog > Manage Products`. Then, click to open the
product in edit mode.

**Step 2:** In the panel on the left, select Gift Options. Then, do the following:
Gift Options

[image]

a. The Allow Gift Message reflects the default configuration. To override the setting,
clear the Use Config Settings checkbox. Then, change the value as needed.

b. To charge for gift wrapping, enter the amount in the Price for Gift Wrapping field,
as a decimal, without the currency symbol.

**Step 3:** When complete, click the Save button.

Comment: That's very nice answer but I want to see the gift card div where customer can put their gift card code

Comment: that will be display in cart page.

Comment: near coupen code block

Comment: can you provide me the path of that template? I updated my question.

Comment: I have not work on enterprise level so I have not idea of that but you can find the template using gif-shop module xml file .

Comment: can't seem to find gift card module

Comment: check in app/code/core/Mage folder